# How to disrupt one power rail if another is connected for powering ESP32?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, esp32

I'm trying to make a DIY ESC with an ESP32. The problem is that, my ESC has 2 power inputs:

1. With an XT60 that powers the mosfets and motor + the ESP32 through a switching buck converter to 3.3V
2. From USB C

I'm not using the ESP S2, but the ESP32-WROOM-32E-N8, which requires a USB-to-UART converter. So I found one (datasheet below), but here's the problem:
**If I power the ESP from both USB AND XT60 at the same time**, this will release the *magic* smoke...
So my question is, **how can we interrupt the USB C VBUS line from powering the ESP32 IF the XT60 is connected?** And enable it again if it's the only power source?

And yes, I tried searching for *"power prioritization ICs"* and found multiple similar to this: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4417f.pdf , but the Output current on the datasheet is "2mA", and I'm quite sure the ESP32 won't operate well at that level... (I think it needs **AT LEAST** 13mA)

Also, I did think about depletion mode normally-closed FETs, whose gate would be connected to the XT60 (+) pin, and whenever it is connected it would interrupt the USB line (VBUS, not D-,D+,GND), but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this... Like what if it doesn't close *INSTANTLY*?

Serial to UART Datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_FT231X-13571.pdf .

Comment: please don't add info in comments ... edit the question and delete the comment ... `forgot to say "Hello!"` ... even though it is polite, it is irrelevant clutter in the question ... this site is not a chat forum ... you post a clear question and somebody will post a clear answer, nothing more

Comment: Do you need to feed the ESP via USB? It could be enough to feed only the UART converter and just connect the control lines to the ESP. What is an XT60? A schematic of the supply model will help here.

Comment: The USB-C port supplies 5V, correct?  Does that also supply the 3.3V buck?
My first inclination would be to use diodes here, assuming you have the voltage headroom for a diode drop.  If each supply passes through a diode, either can supply power, but they won't fight each other.

Comment: @Jens Yes, we do need to feed the ESP via USB. XT60 is a power socket type for LIPos to enter on the board

Comment: @Troutdog Yes, that would also get into the 3.3V Buck. But how is it possible to get them through a Diode? I'm planning on using MAX 12S Lipos on my ESC, so that would be a max voltage around 50V... Isn't it unsafe to feed 3.6-5V from the USB and 50V from the lipo into the 3.3V converter that supplies the ESP?

Comment: The big picture is unclear to me.  Maybe a block diagram would help?
Are you making a custom PCB for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [LTC4417](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4417.html) is a power *controller*, which means that you must connect external MOSFETs to switch the power lines.

> [image: LTC4117 typical application]

There also are power muxes with integrated switches (e.g., [TPS2116](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2116)):

> [image: TPS2116]

The disadvantage of integrated switches is that they must be small and thus have a limited current capability (2500 mA for the TPS2116).